# How to avoid the duplicate UILocalNotification in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

In my app iam using UILocalNotifications.But my requirement is, I want to cancel the duplicate notifiction.

Here my code is.....

```
-(void)LocalNotificationMethod{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    // Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate =  self.selectedDate;
    NSLog(@" self.selectedDate %@", self.selectedDate);
    // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];

    // Set up the fire time
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    // Notification will fire in one minute
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
    [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

    NSLog(@"itemDate %@",itemDate);
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
      NSLog(@"itemDate %@", localNotif.fireDate);
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    // Notification details
    localNotif.alertBody = [_titleTextFieldObj text];
    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    NSLog(@" localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber ++ %ld", (long)localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber );



    // Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[_titleTextFieldObj text] forKey:@"someKey"];

    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;
    NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    //UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"notif %@",notificationArray);


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];


   }
```

I am new to the Objective-c.I don't know where to write the code to not allow the duplicate notifications.Can anyone please help me to solve this.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

A local notification has a `userInfo` property which you can use to put some custom info and can be used to pair your notifications. What I suggest is you use this info to insert an `NSDictionary` including your notification type. For instance:

```
NSString *newNotificationType = @"my_notification";
newNotification.userInfo = @{@"notification_type_key":newNotificationType};
```

Then after you implemented this you can create a check if this type of notification already exists and either cancel the previous one or cancel creation of the new one:

```
for(UILocalNotification *notification in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications])
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    if([userInfo isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && [userInfo[@"notification_type_key"] isEqualToString:newNotificationType])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
    }
}
```

Comment: What about when you have set a notification's repeat interval to repeat every hour or every day/etc..?? That will show the same notification again and again which is GOOD.... but.... is there a way to automatically delete/dismiss the older notifications when the new repeat is posted?

Comment: I never really used that but could you not simply delete the old repeating notification(s) and create a new one? You could probably cancel the notification, then modified the same notification and schedule again this same notification object which now has modified values.

Comment: I see what your saying but that is if the app is running. What about when he user sets a notification to repeat and then closes the app? Then the notification continues to repeat (which is what I want), but the notification centre ends up with a long list of duplicate notifications. There has to be a way to automatically delete duplicate notifications (and just keep the latest one).

Comment: I am not sure you can actually do that. The notification center is an OS feature and there are no settings on that which I can find. You may do it in the code but the application must be activated. So the question is really how to activate the application with a local notification (works with push notifications but might with local as well) or how to limit the number of notifications shown in notification center (which seems to be an OS setting).

Comment: Yeah thats fair enough, I will try my best to limit the number of local notifications I set in the first place. Thanks.